# Use condition in a specific row of a list in a list adapter in android

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a class **LanguagesListAdapter** and I want to use condition for rows to show an image in a specific row. TextViews values are correct but ImageView for each row make visible. My code is here:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  mcontex.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.language_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.langTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.languageTextView);
        holder.langTextView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        holder.check = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_lang);
        holder.check.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.langTextView.setText(languages[position]);

    if (session.getLanguage().equals("fa") && languages[position].equals("farsi")) {

        holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (session.getLanguage().equals("en") && languages[position].equals("English")) {

        holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

and my list XML is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/languageTextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/check_lang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_check_dark"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I fix it to make ImageView  visible just in a specific row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If view is recycled (which means convertView is not null), ImageView will not gone. So add `else` statement to make `ImageView` gone.

```
if (session.getLanguage().equals("fa") && languages[position].equals("farsi")) {    
    holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else if (session.getLanguage().equals("en") && languages[position].equals("English")) {
    holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.check.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```